# Laravel: use database created in WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, wamp

I created a database using WAMP. Now I have to move everything to Laravel.
How can I use this database?
I have a lot of stored procedures written there, I would really like to use them again.

I tried changing .env file and config/database.php file, but it won't help.

config/database.php

```
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db_file'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'psi'),
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'latin2_general_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => true,
'engine' => null,
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=db_file

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=psi
```

Comment: The changes you made are not telling us what you did wrong. 
Show us the rest of env file. Besides you should not edit anything in config/database.php file to use MySQL database

Comment: What's the problem actually ?

Comment: try {
    DB::connection()->getPdo();
 echo 1;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration.");
}

Comment: line above always goes to die

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to configure both env and database.php.Configure one.I recommend you to configure env file .You need a model to access the database.
Models-
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent
Controllers-
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers
Always follow the documentation

Comment: when I set 'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

it works, but when I change username to a wrong one intentionally, it doesn't work again

Comment: I tried changing only .env, it says that everything's OK (function in comment above sets echo 1), but when i set wrong password, it still connects...

Comment: leave them as default.I recommend you to configure env file.That all.When you are configure things such as SMTP or  DB connection always do that in env.Yes it is possible to do it in database.php.But follow the standards

Comment: It is not possible to connect when password in incorrect

Comment: Run a query and see the result.Just try that. Syntax-https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database

Comment: What is your database collation, and what is your username table collation?

Comment: I can connect now, even with wrong username and password...
No idea what's going on...

Comment: As you change the both env and and databse.php .I think one of those are still having correct user name and  password.That must be the reason